# Laravel multiple image uploads using for loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm in a situation where I will have to upload some pictures based on user needs. A user may have 1, 2 or more then 3++ children. So I'm using a `for` loop while uploading his children images. Here is my form:

```
@for($i=1;$i<=$ticket->children_count;$i++)
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Child {{ $i }} Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="child_name_{{$i}}" value="" required="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="">Child {{ $i }} Photo:</label>
       <input type="file" name="child_picture_{{$i}}" value="" required="">
    </div>
 @endfor
```

I want to receive the file from backend but somehow I'm getting null. 
Here is the `for` loop inside the controller:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $ticket->children_count ; $i++) {
            $file = $request->file("child_picture_.$i");
            dd($request->child_name_.$i);
}
```

The above code returns only the value of $i. How do I receive the file properly? It has to be something like `child_name_1` or `child_name_2` `child_picture_1` or `child_picture_3` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the following:

```
dd($request->child_name_.$i);
// php thinks that you are providing two variables:
// $request->child_name_ and $i
```

To:

```
dd($request->{'child_name_'.$i});
// makes sure php sees the whole part
// as the name of the property
```

**Edit**

And for the file, replace:

```
$file = $request->file("child_picture_.$i");
```

To:

```
$file = $request->file("child_picture_" . $i);
```

Comment: this worked for the name but how to print inside of $request->file() part?

Comment: Why not using arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, but for **multiple files** you should use arrays (maintainability, readability), like this:

```
@for($i=1;$i<=$ticket->children_count;$i++)
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Child {{ $i }} Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="child_names[]" value="" required="" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="">Child {{ $i }} Photo:</label>
   <input type="file" name="child_pictures[]" value="" required="">
</div>
@endfor
```

And in your controller check the request has file like so:

```
if ($request->hasFile('child_pictures')) {
    $files = $request->file('child_pictures');

    foreach($files as $file) {
        var_dump($file); // dd() stops further executing!
    }
}
```